# Double decorator, why isn't one of my enclosed functions executed?

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to understand how to use two decorators on one function with the following code:

```
def fxn(func):
    print("fxn_outer 1")
    def fxn_inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("fxn_inner 1")
    return fxn_inner

def fxn2(func):
    print("fxn_outer 2")
    def fxn_inner2(*args, **kwargs):
        print("fxn_inner 2")
    return fxn_inner2

@fxn
@fxn2
def fxn3 (a, b):
    print(a + b)

fxn3(1, 2)
```

I'm confused as to why `fxn_inner` is executed in the above code, but `fxn_inner2` is not.

The output is:

```
fxn_outer 2
fxn_outer 1
fxn_inner 1
```

When I would have expected the following output:

```
fxn_outer 2
fxn_outer 1
fxn_inner 1
fxn_inner 2
```

Why is only one of the two wrapped functions being executed when I called them both?

Comment: Because neither of your wrapper functions calls the function it wraps?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that doesn't make a difference. Even if I call the function in both wrapped functions it is still only executed 1 time. I used `print` statements for simplicity

Comment: @Matt it DOES make a difference, cf Giacomo Alzetta's answer. To make a long story short: it's not executed because you don't call it.

Comment: That's not true at all. If I add the calls I see the expected behaviour.

Comment: I recognize I'm wrong here but not understanding why. I'm going to mull over @Giacomo's answer for a bit

Comment: Perhaps you could give a [mcve] that showed the calls you were making? Just printing is *not* representative of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decorators are just syntactic sugar for calling the function and reassigning the name so what you are doing is equivalent to this:

```
fxn3 = fxn2(fxn3)
fxn3 = fxn(fxn3)

fxn3(1, 2)
```

So what is happening? After the first assignment you have `fxn3 == fxn2_inner`.
After the second line you have `fxn3 == fxn_inner`.

but the definition of `fxn` (and `fxn_inner`) they just throw away the parameter `func`! Hence you don't see it called when you call `fxn3(1,2) == fxn_inner(1, 2)`.

If you want the original function to be called you should call `func` inside the `*_inner` functions:

```
def fxn(func):
    print("fxn_outer 1")
    def fxn_inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("fxn_inner 1")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return fxn_inner

def fxn2(func):
    print("fxn_outer 2")
    def fxn_inner2(*args, **kwargs):
        print("fxn_inner 2")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return fxn_inner2
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't execute the function given to the decorator (the wrapped function) in the body of your decorator. So, the execution stops in the body of the first decorator (i.e. `fxn_inner`).

Usually, what you do with decorators, is to call (invoke) the decorated function within the decorator, i.e.

```py
def fxn(func):
    print("fxn_outer 1")
    def fxn_inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("fxn_inner 1")
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return fxn_inner

def fxn2(func):
    print("fxn_outer 2")
    def fxn_inner2(*args, **kwargs):
        print("fxn_inner 2")
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return fxn_inner2

@fxn
@fxn2
def fxn3 (a, b):
    print(a + b)

fxn3(1, 2)
```

Comment: In your example the script only spits out the output from `fxn3` once. However, you called it twice (once in each wrapped function) - I still don't understand the root cause of why this is happening

Comment: @Matt you don't call it twice; the `func` is *not* the same object in each wrapper, in `fxn` you're wrapping `fxn2_inner`.

Comment: @Matt Note that `func` is *bound* to two different functions. Inside `fxn_inner` the value of `func` is `fxn2_inner` and inside `fxn2_inner` it is bound to `fxn3`. It's "chain calling".